# C++ enum not properly recognized by compiler

Tags: c++, enums, constructor, temporary

Can anyone explain why the following code does not compile (on g++ (GCC) 3.2.3 20030502 (Red Hat Linux 3.2.3-49))?

```
struct X {
public:
   enum State { A, B, C };

   X(State s) {}
};

int main()
{
   X(X::A);
}
```

The message I get is:

jjj.cpp: In function 'int main()':
jjj.cpp:10: 'X X::A' is not a static member of 'struct X'
jjj.cpp:10: no matching function for call to 'X::X()'
jjj.cpp:1: candidates are: X::X(const X&)
jjj.cpp:5:                 X::X(X::State)`

Is this bad code or a compiler bug?

Problem solved by Neil+Konrad.  See the comments to Neil's answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
X(X::A);
```

is being seen a s a function declaration. If you really want this code, use:

```
(X)(X::A);
```

Comment: The parentheses certainly solve the problem, but I'm not sure how this can be seen as a function declaration, given that X::A is not a type.  Syntactically, it could be a type, but then X x(X::A) would be just as ambiguous.

Comment: My reading of the error message is that the compiler thinks it's an anonymous object being copy-constructed.  That's why it's talking about "X X::A" and not plain "X::A".  But I can't understand why it thinks that.

Comment: Ari: I'm actually confused by the error message myself because it's the same when you omit all parentheses, and this is clearly (for the compiler) a variable declaration (A of type X, inside scope X). But it *should* be treated as a function declaration by the compiler, according to the standard.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said "trying to see it as a declaration". Obviously if it could, there would be no error - it just wouldn't do what you expected.

Comment: Konrad, I think you nailed it.  It's disregarding the parentheses and treating it as a var decl.  It's the same issue that explains the need for `typename` in templates.

Comment: P.S. "Disregard" is not the right term here.  Var decls are allowed to contain parens.

Comment: X(X::A)  <- that isn't a function declaration tho. It can't, because there is no name. It's seen as the declaration of a static object of X (parens are redundant): X X::A; thus, it thinks A is an object of type X in class X, and is looking for a default constructor of class X.

Comment: (there are two ambiguities: an expression statement that also syntactically looks like a declaration ( { int a; int(a); } << bug, redefinition of a ) as is the case here. and secondly, a declaration that can declare both a function and an object). both issues are because redundant parens are allowed

Answer (score 10):

You've forgot the variable name in your definition:

```
int main()
{
   X my_x(X::A);
}
```

Your code confuses the compiler because syntactically it can't distinguish this from a  function declaration (returning `X` and passing `X::A` as an argument). When in doubt, the C++ compiler always disambiguates in favour of a declaration.

The solution is to introduce redundant parentheses around the `X` since the compiler forbids parentheses around types (as opposed to constructo calls etc.):

```
(X(X::A));
```

Comment: Ah, no, actually.  I'm trying to create a temporary.  If I add another constructor, say, X(int a) {}, I can do X(5); and it compiles fine.  It's only the enum that causes trouble.

Comment: I've updated my answer, and given an alternative to Neil's solution.

Comment: Please see my comment to neil.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it crystal clear what happens. Look at this example

```
int main() {
    float a = 0;
    {
        int(a); // no-op?
        a = 1;
    }
    cout << a;
}
```

What will it output? Well, it will output `0`. The `int(a)` of above can be parsed in two different ways:

- Cast to int and discard the result
- Declare a variable called `a`. But ignore the parentheses around the identifier.

The compiler, when such a situation appears where a function-style cast is used in a statement and it looks like a declaration too, will always take it as a declaration. When it can't syntactically be a declaration (the compiler will look at the whole line to determine that), it will be taken to be an expression. Thus we are assigning to the inner `a` above, leaving the outer `a` at zero.

Now, your case is exactly that. You are trying (accidentally) to declare an identifier called `A` within a class called `X`:

```
X (X::A); // parsed as X X::A;
```

The compiler then goes on to moan about a not declared default constructor, because the static, as it assumes it to be, is default constructed. But even if you had a default constructor for X, it of course is still wrong because neither `A` is a static member of X, nor a static of X can be defined/declared at block scope.

You can make it *not* look like a declaration by doing several things. First, you can paren the whole expression, which makes it not look like a declaration anymore. Or just paren the type that is cast to. Both of these disambiguations have been mentioned in other answers:

```
(X(X::A)); (X)(X::A)
```

There is a similar, but distinct ambiguity when you try to actually declare an object. Look at this example:

```
int main() {
    float a = 0;
    int b(int(a)); // object or function?
}
```

Because `int(a)` can be both the declaration of a parameter called `a` and the explicit conversion (cast) of the float-variable to an int, the compiler decides again that that is a declaration. Thus, we happen to declare a function called `b`, which takes an integer argument and returns an integer. There are several possibilities how to disambiguate that, based on the disambiguation of above:

```
int b((int(a))); int b((int)a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare an object as

```
X x(X::A);
```

Bug in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Either of these two lines work for me:

```
X obj(X::A);
X obj2 = X(X::A);
```

As Neil Butterworth points out, `X(X::A)` is being treated as a function declaration.  If you really want an anonymous object, `(X)(X::A)` will construct an X object and immediately delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You could, of course, just do something like this:

```
int main()
{
    // code
    {
    X temp(X::A);
    }
    // more code
}
```

This would be more readable and basically have the same effect.